# MySql: How to display only 1 name only per multiple name

Tags: mysql

To make it more clear, If I have this data in MySql:

```js
name | allowance | age
----------------------
khan | 50        | 20
aal  | 60        | 22
hyme | 50        | 21
khan | 61        | 20
```

notice that there are two '**khan**' in the database with different allowance. I want to only show the name and the age but if I show it using the mysqli select statement, there would be two '**khan**' but I only want to show only 1 '**khan**'. How can I do it?

Comment: Can u please paste ur output here...

Comment: Which of the two khans you want to see?

Comment: put where condition in select query

Comment: did u used limit 0,1 ?

Comment: my expected output would be `khan | 20`, `aal | 22` and `hyme | 21`

Comment: What if there is one more Khan|30 in table.

Comment: then only show 1 khan. either way i just want to show 1 unique name even if there are multiple the same name on the database

Comment: I have given all options, you can pick any one from my answer below.

Comment: If you don't care which one... Well, you *should* care!!

Comment: Incidentally, this is the most frequently asked question on SO under the [mysql] tag. It gets correctly answered quite often too - although sadly that hasn't happened below just yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GROUP_CONCAT to see agges of all Khans;

```
select name, GROUP_CONCAT(age) ages from Table group by name
```

or for minimum aged khan

```
 select name , min(age) MiniumAge from Table group by name
```

or for elder khan

```
 select name , max(age) MaxAge from Table group by name
```

or any khan

```
select name , age from Table group by name
```

.

Comment: up until your last point, you're on track. mysql does NOT guarantee which entry will be returned for age if you don't `group by` it or use it in an aggregate function. It might _seem_ like it returns the first entered entry, but it makes no guarantees that it always will. never rely on this functionality.

Comment: But the op wants the allowance too!

Comment: @Strawberry, No he do not, his expectation is-> my expected output would be khan | 20, aal | 22 and hyme | 21

Comment: If the op did not want the allowance in the output, they would not have included it in the question. But you might be right so I'll give you your point back.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query:-

```
SELECT name, age FROM table_name WHERE group by name
```

If you want any from multiple same record then simply used group by query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this:

```
SELECT name, age FROM table_name WHERE group by name,age
```

Comment: In this case two khans will be displayed, but he want only one.

Comment: @AnilKumar : No because the age is the same

Comment: when a khan can has different age also, he has clarified about this, in all cases he need 1 khan-> either way i just want to show 1 unique name even if there are multiple the same name on the database. You do not need to group by age here.

Comment: @AnilKumar : Yes I know that you do not need to group by age because mysql does it by it self. In any other RDMS this will cause an exception. I just think that it is bad practice not do it

Answer (score 0):

First thing: if both those "khan"s are the same person with two different allowances then your schema is not properly normalized and it will give you big troubles later - imagine you want to change "khan" to "Khan" - now you have to update it in multiple places instead once. Depending on your actual needs you may want one table of people (person_id, name, age), and table of allowances (person_id, allowance, [..some other parameters?..]).

Second, to really get what you want, either you use group by, to get one "random" row per each name as suggested in other answers, or you can do

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, age FROM table;
```

which will give you one  row per each name-age combination, so khan-20 will be there only once - but if there were khan-25 then that is probably different person and you would have two khans returned, each with their own age.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    name, age
FROM
    <your_table>;
```

or this one

```
SELECT
    name, age
FROM
    <your_table>
GROUP BY
    name;
```

**Q:** Is there any chance that if there are 2 records of tha same name have difference value of age? If so, kindly update the question so that better answers will be given. Cheers!